# implementing a lazy Supplier in java

Tags: java, guava, lazy-evaluation

What is the right paradigm or utility class (can't seem to find a preexisting class) to implement a lazy supplier in Java?

I want to have something that handles the compute-once/cache-later behavior and allows me to specify the computation behavior independently. I know this probably has an error but it has the right semantics:

```
abstract public class LazySupplier<T> implements Supplier<T> 
{
    private volatile T t;
    final private Object lock = new Object();

    final public T get() {
        if (t == null)
        {
            synchronized(lock)
            {
                if (t == null)
                    t = compute();
            }
        }
        return t;
    }
    abstract protected T compute();
}
```

Comment: That looks fine to me, what's bothering you?

Comment: I know that concurrency is not something you mess with unless you really take the right steps to make sure it is correct.

Comment: The example code shown here is a double ckecked locking and is bad practice as described in http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Comment: @CarloPellegrini: It was bad prior to volatile fields. It's fine now, as long as you implement it correctly (with `volatile`).

Comment: @ColinD Noted. It was bad before JDK 5 and the new memory model ( JSR 133). Unfortunately at work I'm stuck whith JDK 1.4. Too bad...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is already implemented in [`Suppliers.memoize`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoize-com.google.common.base.Supplier-) method.

```
public static <T> Supplier<T> memoize(Supplier<T> delegate)
```

> Returns a supplier which caches the instance retrieved during the
> first call to get() and returns that value on subsequent calls to
> get(). See: memoization
>
> The returned supplier is thread-safe. The delegate's get() method will
> be invoked at most once. The supplier's serialized form does not
> contain the cached value, which will be recalculated when get() is
> called on the reserialized instance.
>
> If delegate is an instance created by an earlier call to memoize, it
> is returned directly.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Commons Lang has a [LazyInitializer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent/LazyInitializer.html).